# If isometric linear operator is surjective, then the inverse is isometric and bijective

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm working on the following problem which states:

Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces and let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear isometric operator.

(i) Show that if $T$ is surjective then $T^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ is bijective and isometric.

(ii) Give an example of an isometric linear operator which is not surjective. You are free to choose the space $X$.

I believe I have solved it, I guess I'm just looking for clarification whether my solution is correct. Here's my attempt at (i):

If $T^{-1}$ is injective that means if $T^{-1}y=0\Rightarrow y=0$. So applying $T$ on both sides yield $TT^{-1}y=y=0$ (this is possible since $T$ is surjective, i.e., it has a right inverse).

If $T^{-1}$ is surjective that means that for each $x\in X$ there exists a $y\in Y$ such that $T^{-1}y=x$. Thus consider $T^{-1}y$ for an arbitrary $y\in Y$. Since $T$ is surjective that implies there exists an $x\in X$ such that $Tx=y$. This means we have $T^{-1}y=T^{-1}Tx=x$ hence showing $T^{-1}$ is surjective.

For $T^{-1}$ to be isometric we would have that $||T^{-1}y||=||y||$ for all $y\in Y$. Again, from $T$ being surjective we have $||T^{-1}y||=||T^{-1}Tx||=||x||$ thus $T^{-1}$ is an isometry.

For (ii) I chose $X = \ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})$ and $Y=\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ and $T$ as the left-shift operator. Since $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})\subset\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ then $T$ cannot be surjective. I've shown in previous exercises that $T$ is an isometric linear operator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A slightly easier example for the second one $\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For showing that $T^{-1}$ is bijective: You first need to show that $T^{-1}$ exists. Meaning you should show that $T$ is bijective.

Comment: By assumption $T$ is surjective and injectivity follows from $$ \Vert x - y\Vert = \Vert T(x-y) \Vert =  \Vert T(x)-T(y) \Vert $$

Comment: But being surjective still implies the existence of a right inverse? And yes, injectiveness of $T$ is clear since it is an isometry.

Comment: But you are using later on that it is a left inverse as well...

Comment: For me it is just bad style. Showing that $T$ is bijective is two lines and is much more understandable.

Comment: I can see what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

Part two is not correct, for $\|\cdot\|_{l^{1}}\ne\|\cdot\|_{l^{2}}$.

An example would be $T(x)=x$ and $T:c_{00}\rightarrow c_{0}$, the former is all the sequences with eventually zero, the later is all the sequences which vanishing at infinity, both taken in supremum norm.

Comment: Oh yeah, I completely forgot about that. Thanks for the example! Is my solution to (i) correct?

Comment: Almost, but the reasoning is not good enough. For you cannot assume the thing you want to prove at the very beginning.

Comment: What is it that I'm assuming that I want to prove? The existence of $T^{-1}$?

Comment: The very first statement you wrote that "if $T^{-1}$ is surjective..." this is not a good start.

Comment: I wrote it in the sense that this is what it should satisfy to be surjective and then I showed that it was indeed the case. But maybe I should explain myself better